# Select account for VBA script

Tags: vba, outlook

I have written code to limit the number of addresses for the To, CC and BCC fields.

The only problem is the code affects all accounts and not a specific account which I select.

```
e.g: user1@xyz.com
     user2@xyz.com
```

I want this code to work only for the "user1@xyz.com" account and not the "user2@xyz.com" account. But the code is running in the whole Outlook session. Is there any option to choose the account in the code?

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Element As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim aaa() As String
    Dim bbb() As String
    Dim ccc() As String
    aaa = Split(Element.To, ";")
    bbb = Split(Element.CC, ";")
    ccc = Split(Element.BCC, ";")
    If (UBound(aaa) + 1) + (UBound(bbb) + 1) + (UBound(ccc) + 1) > 10 Then
        MsgBox ("You have added too many recipients! Please contact your Administrator."), vbExclamation, "Authorization required!"
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: your content format is not proper first edit format

Comment: @DenishParvadiaThank you Denish, I have fixed the format now. Please take a look on this.

Comment: your code is not proper see

Comment: @DenishParvadia Sorry partial content was posted. Its fixed now

Comment: Do you mean you want the code to be active when a message is sent through a specific account/ Or only  when it is being sent to a specific address?

Comment: Hi. I want to run it from a specific account.

Comment: Check `Environ("Username")` and either run or not based on the response?

Comment: I tried but I am unable to implement it. Could you edit the code to get me an idea.

Answer (score 0):

I've written a lot of VBA, but none for Outlook, so I'm guessing a bit here. How about inserting this before you Split anything:

```
If LCase(Environ("Username") & "@" & Environ("Userdnsdomain")) <> "user1@xyz.com" Then Exit Sub
```

?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the applicable account like this

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Element As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

Dim oAccount As account

For Each oAccount In Session.Accounts

    If oAccount = "user1@xyz.com" Then

        Dim aaa() As String
        Dim bbb() As String
        Dim ccc() As String
        aaa = Split(Element.To, ";")
        bbb = Split(Element.CC, ";")
        ccc = Split(Element.BCC, ";")

        If (UBound(aaa) + 1) + (UBound(bbb) + 1) + (UBound(ccc) + 1) > 1 Then
            MsgBox ("You have added too many recipients! Please contact your Administrator."), vbExclamation, "Authorization required!"
            Cancel = True
        End If

    End If
Next

ExitRoutine:
    Set oAccount = Nothing

End Sub
```